# Leaflet re-render a map with new data in a React app

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, maps

given the following implementation:

```
getCurrentMap() {
  const {currentlyActiveMap: {task, type, layout}} = this.mapStore
  if (this.currentMap) this.currentMap.eachLayer(layer => {
    this.currentMap.removeLayer(layer)
  })

  let centerX = 0
  let centerY = 0

  if (layout.image_width > layout.image_height) {
    centerX = layout.tile_size / 2
    centerY = (layout.tile_size * layout.image_height / layout.image_width) / 2
  } else {
    centerX = (layout.tile_size * layout.image_width / layout.image_height) / 2
    centerY = layout.tile_size / 2
  }

  this.currentMap = this.currentMap || Leaflet.map(this.map, {
    center: [-centerY, centerX],
    crs: Leaflet.CRS.Simple,
    minZoom: 0,
    maxZoom: layout.max_zoom_level + 1,
    maxBounds: [[layout.tile_size, -layout.tile_size], [-2 * layout.tile_size, 2 * layout.tile_size]],
    doubleClickZoom: false,
    attributionControl: false,
    zoom: 2
  })

  let currentLayer = Leaflet.tileLayer(`${layout.tiling_url}`)
  this.currentMap.addLayer(currentLayer)

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <button type='button' className={styles.mapPanelCreateButton} onClick={this.handleCreateTask}>
        <FaPlus/>
      </button>
    </Fragment>
  )
}


render() {
  const mapLayout = !!this.taskStore.loading || !this.mapStore.currentlyActiveMap
    ? <LoadingContainer transparent={true}/>
    : this.getCurrentMap()

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div id='map' className={styles.mapPanelContainer} ref={map => this.map = map}></div>
      {mapLayout}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

I am unable to render the map, and I am also unable to update/swap or otherwise change the data within the map (need to switch between custom tiled image and global map).  Ids there something inherently wrong with this implementation or is there a better case to achieve this?

As always any and all direction is appreciated, so thanks in advance!

also another implementation with the same result:

`` Leaflet.tileLayer(`${layout.tiling_url}`).addTo(this.currentMap) ``

EDIT: Im also receiving the infamous:
**Uncaught Error: Map container is already initialized.**

Comment: If you're going to be using `react` in combination with `leaflet` I would highly recommend using the `react-leaflet` package. https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet
Also if you have a fiddle or codepen with a minimal example of what you want to do I can help you convert over to using `react-leaflet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I thought I would swing back and provide my solution:

@jbccollins thanks for the suggestion, but I need more low level customization that react-leaflet cannot provide without a PR.  I would love to contribute, but I just don't have the time to wait for the inclusion.

```
this.locationLayer = Leaflet.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/rastertiles/voyager/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png')
this.floorPlanLayer = Leaflet.tileLayer(layout.tiling_url)

this.currentMap = Leaflet.map(this.map, options)
this.locationLayer.addTo(this.currentMap)

if (this.currentMap.hasLayer(this.locationLayer)) {
    this.currentMap.addLayer(this.floorPlanLayer)
    this.currentMap.removeLayer(this.locationLayer)
    this.currentLayer = this.floorPlanLayer
  } else {
    this.currentMap.addLayer(this.locationLayer)
    this.currentMap.removeLayer(this.floorPlanLayer)
    this.currentLayer = this.locationLayer
  }
```